# What is the use-case for .NET's "U" (Universal Full) DateTime format specifier?

Tags: .net, datetime, format, date-formatting

(Preface: This question is not intended to be overly broad nor opinion-based, though it necessarily is subjective).

I was tracking down a bug in my software which used `dtValue.ToString( "U", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )` instead of `dtValue.ToString( "u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )`.

(I suppose this happened because while `"R"` and `"r"`, and `"O"` and `"o"` differ in letter-case, .NET treats them identically, whereas `"U"` and `"u"` represent very different formats and behaviours).

After fixing that issue, I looked at t[he documentation for the `U` format out of curiosity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-full-u-format-specifier) and questioned why it exists in the first place because I cannot think of a use-case for `U`.

For those wondering: `U` does this:

1. If it's a `DateTimeOffset` value, then a `FormatException` is thrown, always.
2. If it's a `DateTime` value, then internally it's converted to UTC using `DateTime.ToUniversalTime`:

   - If `value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc` then no conversion is done.
   - If `value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local` or `Unspecified` then the local computer's system timezone's current UTC offset is applied to convert it to UTC.
3. Then the value is formatted using the `"F"` format (`DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern`), which is culture-specific.

   - `InvariantCulture` uses `"dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.
   - `en-US` uses `"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`.
   - `en-GB` uses `"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

My reasoning:

- Because the format is culture-specific, it cannot be used for machine-to-machine communication.

  - Unless you use `InvariantCulture` of course, but the resulting output string has redundant information (day-name) and difficult to parse information (English language full month names), whereas machine-readable formatting invariably uses a variation of ISO 8601's `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss][zzz]`.
- Information is lost in the conversion, such as local time or local UTC offset.
- Often programs will be processing different `DateTime` values without ever considering `DateTimeKind` (e.g. programs using a `DateTimeKind.Local` value as though it represents UTC, especially if the local computer's time-zone is UTC or UK time (and so you get interesting bugs during British Summer Time).

  - So if you're going to `switch` or branch on `dtValue.Kind` to be explicit about converting to UTC then you may-as-well use `F` and avoid `U`'s implicit UTC conversion.
  - I expected `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` values formatted with `U` to throw an exception because the value's offset is *unspecified* - it's surprising that `ToUniversalTime()` uses the local computer's timezone's current offset (as with `Local`) instead of complaining about making an assumption. (Still, this is why we should be using `DateTimeOffset` or [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/#info) wherever possible, of course).
- `DateTimeOffset` simply doesn't support it (presumably this was intentional to wean .NET programmers from using it?).

My question:

"Have you ever intentionally used the `U` format-specifier or seen it used in production code? Why? Was it a good idea at the time and is it still a good choice?"

Comment: Sounds like it is for *displaying* to the user, for the reference, what time in UTC their chosen local datetime value is.

Comment: @GSerg That would make sense if it included an explicit `Z` or other indicator that it's a UTC value.